# How to fix "Cannot assign a TSkGraphic to a TBitmap"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, skia4delphi

I use Skia4Delphi in my VCL application. I have an Image1 (TImage) component. It supports loading webp image files thanks to Skia4Delphi. However I get "**Cannot assign a TSkGraphic to a TBitmap**" error when I try to convert a webp image to TBitmap. No error message for PNG or JPEG files.

Here is an example code:

```
uses System.Skia, VCL.Skia;

var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('c:\image.webp'); // No error
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic); // Error for webp files
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How to fix the error and load the webp image into TBitmap?

Comment: Untested, but: Try saving it to a TMemoryStream as a .BMP file (Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create; Image1.Picture.BitMap.SaveToStream(Stream)) and then load it into your TBitmap  (Stream.Position:=0; Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream))

Comment: @HeartWare Thank you for the idea. But SaveToStream makes the Image invisible somehow.

Comment: While Skia4Delphi registers various additional codecs that include ability to open more image file types it is not necessary that it also registers needed codecs for direct conversion between `TSkGraphic` and `TBitmap` graphic types.  But from what I see in Skia4Delphi documentation you can edit `TBitmap` by using Skia's Canvas

Comment: @HeartWare what you described won't work. Accessing the `Picture.Bitmap` property when the `Picture` is not holding a `TBitmap` will wipe out the current image and replace it with a blank `TBitmap`. This is [documented behavior](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap).

Comment: You can paint it to bitmap canvas:
bitmap.canvas.draw(0,0,image1.picture.graphic);
Set bitmap.Width and Height first.

Comment: @Robert This approach works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14857696/robert) wrote as a comment works.

```
uses System.Skia, VCL.Skia;

var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('c:\image.webp'); // No error
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    //Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic); // Error for webp files
    Bitmap.Width:=Image1.Picture.Width;
    Bitmap.Height:=Image1.Picture.Height;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Image1.Picture.Graphic);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```